# Build works for iOS 7, but crashes in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, crash

I've been making an app and only testing in iOS 7 simulator until now, and I wanted to try and build for iOS 6, to see if it looks good. Problem is, I get a mysterious crash when I build for iOS 6. iOS 7 is still just fine, but iOS 6 doesn't start. The file editor goes to main.m, and the debugger shows this:

```
2014-03-10 21:45:55.481 Can'Art 2014[4479:907] -[UINavigationController interactivePopGestureRecognizer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x797d720
2014-03-10 21:45:55.483 Can'Art 2014[4479:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController interactivePopGestureRecognizer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x797d720'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x179d012 0x15c2e7e 0x18284bd 0x178cbbc 0x178c94e 0xbb5b 0x814817 0x814882 0x814b2a 0x82bef5 0x82bfdb 0x82c286 0x82c381 0x82ceab 0x82cfc9 0x82d055 0x9323ab 0x78392d 0x15d66b0 0x424fc0 0x41933c 0x424eaf 0x8228cd 0x76b1a6 0x769cbf 0x769bd9 0x768e34 0x768c6e 0x769a29 0x76c922 0x816fec 0x763bc4 0x763dbf 0x763f55 0x76cf67 0x730fcc 0x731fab 0x743315 0x74424b 0x735cf8 0x2928df9 0x1720f3f 0x172096f 0x1743734 0x1742f44 0x1742e1b 0x7317da 0x73365c 0xb23d 0x264970d)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I've been searching for errors in my project, and everything I've found up until now is that in Copy Bundle Resources, in Build Phases, Main.storyboard is red. I assumed this means that it can't localize the Main.storyboard file, but readding the references and readding it to the Copy Bundle Resources didn't work. It also stays red when building for iOS 7, even though it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Stacktrace says, that you are trying to use interactive pop gesture which is not available in iOS6. 
You can use respondsToSelector: to check if your instance can send such kind of message.

For ex.

```
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
```